# Create a TypeScript object and define its type based on constraints from an input object

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a function which takes an object `A: { [key: string]: string | undefined }` as input, and outputs a new object `B` such that all properties in `A` are present in `B`, each `string` property is transformed into `number`, and each `string | undefined` property is transformed into `number | undefined`.

This illustrates the general idea:

```js
type In<T> = { [K in keyof T]: string | undefined };
type Out<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? number | undefined : number };

function transformObject<T extends In<T>>(input: T): Out<T> {
  const result = {} as Out<T>;
  for (const key in input) {
    const value = input[key];
    result[key] = value === undefined ? undefined : value.length;
  }
  return result;
}

const obj = { background: 'red', color: 'blue', border: undefined };
const obj2 = transformObject(obj);
const bgLength: number = obj2.background;
const borderLength: number | undefined = obj2.border;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to type cast the assignment to `result[key]`. Without the `as any` type cast. I get the following error:

```
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] extends undefined ? number | undefined : number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] extends undefined ? number | undefined : number'.ts(2322)
```

What's the correct way to declare this type of relationship between the input and output objects, where all properties in `A` are declared to be in `B`, while also maintaining optional properties as optional in `B`?

Comment: (continued)  If so, the issue is essentially that TS *defers* evaluation of generic conditional types like `T[K] extends undefined ? undefined : string` where `T` and `K` are generic type parameters.  That means it has no idea what specific values might actually be assignable to such a type, unless they happen to have an identical generic conditional type themselves.  But `input[key] === undefined ? undefined : "green"` is just of type `"green" | undefined`, which is not known to be assignable to that (no, `input[key] === undefined` has no effect on `T` or `T[K]`), so you're stuck.  (more)

Comment: (continued): the canonical issue about this is [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Does this fully address the question?  If so, and if you [edit] to remove the top code sample and the description around it, and just focus on the bottom one, then I'll write up a full answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the suggestion. I've simplified the question now.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was just a leftover that I've now removed.

Comment: @jcalz I think ms/TS#33912 may be describing the same issue, but it seems like my example has the additional quirk of applying a conditional type to the properties of an object, instead of the return type of a function. I'm not sure if that makes this problem distinct or not.

Comment: It's the same issue; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEYnyw). If that covers things I'll write up a full answer.

Comment: Sure, give it a go. 
I guess that your type cast to Out<T>[K] denotes the union of the conditional type for all keys, not any specific one, right? That’s a bit broad, but I guess the best that be done as a workaround for this TypeScript issue?

Comment: Actually `Out<T>[K]` is quite specific, since I refactored the loop in the playground link to make `K` another generic type parameter. It's for each specific key.  But without support for ms/TS#33912 it's overkill to do that. In my answer below I'm using `Out<T>[keyof T]` which *is* the union for all keys. Maybe if ms/TS#33912 is ever supported we'd want to use the generic refactoring to use `K extends keyof T` instead of `keyof T`, but there's not much point now since it requires a type assertion. Why bother getting the right size nut for a bolt if we're just duct-taping them together anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside

```
function transformObject<T extends In<T>>(input: T): Out<T> {
  const result = {} as Out<T>;
  for (const key in input) {
    const value = input[key];
    result[key] = value === undefined ? undefined : value.length; // error
  }
  return result;
}
```

the `result` variable is of type `Out<T>`, a type written in terms of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`. When you try to assign a value to the property at the `key` key of type `keyof T` (well, it's `Extract<keyof T, string>` using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) because `for`-`in` loops skip `symbol` properties... let's just use `keyof T` here though), then the compiler checks the type, `Out<T>[keyof T]`, and sees that it needs to be of the generic conditional type `T[keyof T] extends undefined ? number | undefined : number`.

But TypeScript is notoriously unable to do much analysis of generic conditional types like this.  Such types are usually left mostly unevaluated, and are thus opaque to the type checker.  If you try to assign a specific value to such a type, unless the value is of the identical type to the one you're assigning to, the type checker has no idea if it's a valid assignment or not.  The expression `value === undefined ? undefined : value.length` is of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `number | undefined`.  That is not identical to `T[keyof T] extends undefined ? number | undefined : number`, so the compiler complains.

You might hope that a [conditional expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like `t === v ? y : n` would map neatly onto a conditional *type* like `T extends V ? Y : N`, but it doesn't.  The check `value === undefined` only affects the variable `value`, not its type `T[keyof T]`.  The generic type parameter `T` is completely unaffected by that check.  In other worse, [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does not currently play nicely with generic types.

So you're kind of stuck here.  There are various feature requests in GitHub asking for improved support for situations like this. The most applicable one here is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which explicitly asks for a way to relate control flow like `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` or `?`/`:` to conditional types.  The GitHub issue talks about function return types, but the general issue is assignability, so it's applicable.  Even if only function return types were supported, you could use it to write helper functions to get expressions to work.

In any case, such support is not currently part of the language, and you need to work around it.

---

The most straightforward workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and just *tell* the compiler that it can treat `(value === undefined ? undefined : value.length)` as type `Out<T>[keyof T]`, and move along:

```
function transformObject<T extends In<T>>(input: T): Out<T> {
  const result = {} as Out<T>;
  for (const key in input) {
    const value = input[key];
    result[key] = 
      (value === undefined ? undefined : value.length) as Out<T>[keyof T]; // okay
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here you're taking responsibility for type checking away from the compiler, which can't do it.  That means if you make a mistake in your assertion, the compiler can't really catch it.  So you should be careful.  But there's not really much to be done about that, at least until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#33912 or the like is implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgHgCoD4oF4oG8oG0DSUAlnFANYQgD2AZlEgLoBcUAzsAE4kDmUAPlACucACYQaJCCKgBfANwAoUJCgB5QcGRpMOAsVIVqdRiyQEGUCAA9gEUayGjxk6QH4ocQQFsARhA78jmIScFJQLJ6+-rKKCjTCAMbARFSknACGcKw0VBxeqj4AVhBJAEIcVBSISJY2diIO8FooABQkYBqmAJQs6pqo2ApQUAmp7FAcEKyCADbAGNgyUOkOfVqKwzkBLaNZ84b6+h3AXYPDw7vjAG7pM4LQmO0auIYMG+eT03MvlBaYN3cHuhMMJgi4oO5Qc5QtIWAD7gA6GZ2bjAAAWcigAHosZYOBUOENZETJsBBBxSJ9ZsBFDIFHFEslUlAMlktvkiiVgABBVisfy2ETIWq2eywaooVpPYDdXoaLRnEZjeZUuYLLBLFZqeWod5bKA7ZXkSiHaWnLBEi5G+EPI7PV7vYaq4A-EB-A02jDAoLQsKQpwhMJw26I5FwVFo05ataoV20ehvbG4yrpEBEulOiBkikTKbU2lAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer and generously detailed explanation. I especially appreciate the various links to relevant TypeScript documentation. I'll study the links and may get back to you with a comment or perhaps a clarifying question, if I have one, and you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind as long as the question is within scope of this answer; if it looks like a followup question that needs its own answer then I'd probably ask you to post it separately.